# Why is my bootstrap navbar-expand-sm navigation covering content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

We are having trouble with our responsive navigation covering content.
[image: our navigation is covering the rest of our content when in mobile] When the user toggles the navigation button, we want it to push the H1 and  down the screen. I am thinking that our css for the body is effecting this. I cannot think of a decent solution for this, but I have considered having the navigation have a background, but it will still cover our "Denver Moving and Storage" content.

We're still learning how to use stackoverflow and we're thankful for any help you guys may be able to offer.

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

This is our code:

```
<!-- container with bg img -->
<div class="cover">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- NAV Here -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark d-flex" aria-label="responsive navbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/the-other-side-moving-storage-color-white.png" width="75%" height="75%"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#responsive-navbar" aria-controls="responsive-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="denver-moving-services.html">Moving</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="denver-storage-company.html">Storage</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="receiving-and-delivery.html">Furniture Delivery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="free-estimate.html"><button class="btn btn-tosa" type="submit">Free Estimate</button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Nav end -->
  </div>
  <!-- FS Hero -->
  <div class="container-xl mb-4">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="py-5">Denver Moving and Storage</h1>
        <a href="free-estimate.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-tosa mx-3">Free Estimate</button></a>
        <a href="about-us.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-tosa mx-3">Our Story</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End FS Hero -->
</div>
  <!-- End Cover -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your body CSS is affecting it or not, since you didn't post that out. But just by looking at your HTML, I see something wrong with your button toggler:

```
<button ... data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#responsive-navbar" />
```

Where did you get this kind of syntax from? In [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#supported-content), there is no `-bs` on the data attribute.

In order for the toggler to work properly, you need to remove `-bs`.

##### Minor improvement

Your "free estimate" button. Bootstrap has a button style to make an anchor tag look like a button. You don't need to wrap a button with an anchor tag. You can change it to something like:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="free-estimate.html">Free Estimate</a>
</li>
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/p4ofdcae/8/